How to output custom HTML+JS+CSS from a SQL query field in Grafana?
The table field stores summary information in the form of large text, which I would like to break into logical sections and hide under a spoiler.
Therefore, I see a solution in the form of preparing the HTML text before writing it to the table. But the problem is that I can't figure out how to output this HTML to grafana. Maybe someone has solved a similar problem or has a hint on how best to solve my problem? Thank you very much in advance for your answers.
As a result, I would like to get a text structure like this:
Text
>Spoiler
Text
↓ Spoiler
 Text under spoiler
 Text
 >Spoiler
 Text
 ↓ Spoiler
   Text ...
Text

I tried to build it in the form of a tree, but it is very resource-intensive and there is a very high probability of error.

Solution: I used Dynamic text plugin
